# How to change cell height in Kal calendar

Tags: ios, calendar, tapku, kal

I've set up Kal calendar in my project. I've added my custom cell from xib file. It's shown properly but can't change cell height in any way. Tried in xib file, tried in "heightForRowAtIndexPath" but didn't worked at all.

Anything else I should try?

Comment: anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can change cell height in Kal calendar by modifying values of **kTileSize** mentioned in  **KalGridView**.

```
 
const CGSize kTileSize = { 46.f, 44.f };
```

Apart from that you can change **kHeaderHeight** to increase / decrease header titles also.